# Varnish 'client.ip' not available in method 'vcl_backend_response'

Tags: varnish

Due to server upgrade we had to migrate from Varnish 3 to Varnish 4.
With little experience with the server I have able to update the setup and variables needed for the newer version but unfortunately I have run into a brick wall.

Inside `vcl_backend_response` we need to use `client.ip` but unfortunately it doesn't allow us and it is throwing this error:

```
Message from VCC-compiler:
'client.ip': Not available in method 'vcl_backend_response'.
At: ('input' Line 196 Pos 11)
     if ( client.ip ~ traefik_acl && req.http.X-Forwarded-Host) {
----------#########----------------------------------------------
```

Is there an alternative way to get the client IP inside `vcl_backend_response`?

Full `vcl_backend_response`

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
    if (beresp.http.content-type ~ "text" ||
        beresp.http.content-type ~ "javascript") {
        set beresp.do_gzip = true;
    }

    if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
        beresp.http.Set-Cookie ||
        beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
        /*
         * Mark as "Hit-For-Pass" for the next 2 minutes
         */

        set beresp.ttl = 120 s;
            set beresp.uncacheable = true;  

            return (deliver);
     }

     if ( client.ip ~ traefik_acl  && req.http.X-Forwarded-Host) {
        set bereq.http.header.host = regsub(req.http.X-Forwarded-Host, ":.*$", "");
     }

     return (deliver);
}
```

Comment: What version of Varnish are you using for this?

Comment: @JamesHannah Using Varnish 4 now

Comment: Now that I read your code again, I don’t see the point of setting the X-Forwarded-Host header in **bereq** that late in that subroutine anyway - bereq is thrown away after this subroutine returns? (Unless you’re using it in `vcl.deliver`).

Comment: I think you’d be better just moving that stanza to vcl_recv?

Comment: @JamesHannah Ah I see I get what you mean, unfortunately I can't tell the reason why it was coded since it was created by our previous sys admin. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field `client` isn’t available in the backend worker thread in Varnish v4.x.

As a work around, you can *store* the client’s IP (or in this case probably just the fact that they passed the ACL check) in `req.http` as a new header, and then you can access that same header via `bereq.http` from your `vcl_backend_response` subroutine:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    set req.http.foo = client.ip;
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    set beresp.http.Some-Header = bereq.http.foo;
}
```

You need to generally be careful when using information from the original request in `vcl_backend_response`, as there’s a chance that a response prepared (and cached) for one user might end up getting re-used (served from the cache) for another.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Regarding your warning would it still matter if I only use it for my IF condition? i.e. `if ( bereq.http.foo ~ "127.0.0.1" ) {` ?

Comment: I think you can just remove that whole stanza unless you’re referencing `bereq.http.header.foo` elsewhere. I think that is actually invalid anyway because it’s literally setting a header named `header.foo` in a stanza that then gets almost immediately discarded.